# Use pre-defined EXPORT_TAGS within EXPORT and EXPORT_OK

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have created a couple of EXPORT_TAGS within my module as below,

```
package My::Module;

use strict;
use warnings;

require Exporter;

our @ISA = qw ( Exporter );

our %EXPORT_TAGS = (
    'set1' => [
        qw(
            &func1
            &func2
        )
    ],
    'set2' => [
        qw(
            $var1
            $var2
        )
    ],
    'set3' => [
        qw(
            &sub3
            &sub4
        )
    ]
);

# remaining module code
```

I am now trying to declare the exportable symbols within the EXPORT and EXPORT_OK arrays by simply giving the export tags, instead of specifying each one individually,

```
our @EXPORT = $EXPORT_TAGS { 'set2' };
our @EXPORT_OK = (
    $EXPORT_TAGS { 'set1' },
    $EXPORT_TAGS { 'set3' }
);
```

In my target script, I am invoking my module as below,

```
use My::Module qw ( :set1 :set3 );
```

The module compiles without errors. However, the target script doesn't and I receive the following error when I try to use the variables/function belonging to the module,

`Global symbol "$var1"` requires explicit package name`

What am I missing/overlooking? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The things in `%EXPORT_TAGS` are arrayrefs; you need to dereference them to flatten them into `@EXPORT` and `@EXPORT_OK`. You want to write:

```
our @EXPORT = @{ $EXPORT_TAGS { 'set2' } };
our @EXPORT_OK = (
    @{ $EXPORT_TAGS { 'set1' } },
    @{ $EXPORT_TAGS { 'set3' } },
);
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great for the subroutines, but for some reason I'm getting the variable uninitialized error when I try to access the module variables, even though they have been declared and defined within the module. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: Got it, I was using `my` instead of `our` so the values were not getting shared with my target script.